# Service subscribr error in basic Symfony 5 bundle example

Tags: symfony

I am creating a basic example of a bundle in Symfony 5. 
I am getting this error:

```
"Mine\MyBundle\Controller\LuckyController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?
```

You can find the code at this github repo: https://github.com/karimmtl/Mysymfony5

It seems that I am still missing something. Here is my config/bundles.php content:

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],

    Mine\MyBundle\MineMyBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Comment: Your bundle is missing some important items including an extension which loads the services.yaml file.  Then, since bundles normally don't use autowiring, you need to define and tag your controllers as services. 
 [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173574/symfony-5-service-not-load/61211693#61211693) provides a complete example of a Symfony bundle.

Comment: @Cerad, thank you very much for your comments.  I will look at the post that you mentioned. If I still can't figure it out I am gonna update the repository with the full code (including) symfony files to make it easier for people to help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Cerad, you are right. Adding the controller info in services.yml didn't make a difference. I am still having the same error. I added some new code and I changed the repo url to include symfony code outside of the bundle.

Comment: Your extension class has the wrong name.  Symfony has a very strict documented default naming convention though you could override it.  Stick a die statement in the class until you confirm it is getting called.

Comment: @Cerad, Do you think it would be useful to other users to add you comments as an answer so that I mark it as the correct answer to my original question? Everything works for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Before starting anything I'd suggest you to go through documentation : [Symfony Bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html)

Now to get to your problem :
If you see project created by symfony, you would find that controllers are by default exposed as services, this can be achieved via defining entry on services.yaml file in config.
This config enables controllers to expose themselves to container :

```
# controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
# as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

You are defining custom bundle, thus your controllers must be loaded and imported accordingly. Just create same entry with proper name spaces in your bundle config and it will start recognizing your controller classes and inject service container along with other auto wired services.

Edit :
For private bundles, you can use autowiring features, but if you are creating a bundle which can be used as 3rd party users, you should explicitly define & tag each controllers & other services to minimize autowiring conflicts. It's standard practice to load bundle config to main app.

[Read more about autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)

[Read More about service tags](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html)

[Controller Fetching Services & Dependencies](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services)

Comment: Actually, bundles seldom use autowiring.  You will need to define and tag controller services manually.

Comment: That is exactly what stated in answer, just expose controller folder same as default app config does.

Comment: Which will do absolutely nothing unless you have autowire enabled.  Which is not recommended for bundles.

Comment: While you are right about not using auto-wiring in bundles documents specifically suggests not to use for public bundles, it still works as any other code and service loader detects them as normal classes. [ Auto-Wiring Consequences] (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#public-and-reusable-bundles).  You can use autowiring feature to reduce amount of services description writing for your bundles, as you know about it's dependencies and conflicts. The reason is to minimize conflicts and config errors in 3rd party libraries. I've updated answer to match the risk.

Comment: Well okay.  I think it might be better to have your answer reflect what is actually needed in services.yml and it might also be nice to include the code necessary for actually loading services.yml in a bundle.  And at the risk of being really pedantic, since the OP's controller extends AbstractController you don't actually need the controller lines in services.yaml at all.